# Check if access to photos is allowed [Phonegap]

Tags: ios, cordova

Do you know how to check if access to photos is allowed in iOS using Phonegap/Cordova ? I am using the FilterImage plugin and there is no way to check if access to photos is allowed when saving a photo to photo library. I want to show a message to user when access to photos is disabled in device settings. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

SDK does not provide direct method for checking specific permissions but you can check if a user has granted permission to your application by checking permissions connection of user object in Graph API

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions" andDelegate:self];
```

or 
    GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions